# Предотвращение memory leaks на Python

Tags: python, сборщик-мусора

Разбирая код на питоне, в очередной раз столкнулся со сложностями, которые возникают при анализе memory leaks. В данном случае это решилось разрезанием ссылок через установку None в одном из полей объекта в коллекции.

Cублимированный код без лишних деталей:

```
from typing import List


class Something(object):

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self.something_new = None


class SomethingNew(object):

    def __init__(self, i: int = 0, something: Something = None) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self.i = i
        self.something = something


def add_something(collection: List[Something], i: int):
    something = Something()
    something.something_new = SomethingNew(i, something)
    collection.append(something)


def check_memory(collection: List[Something]):
    # for e in collection:
    #     e.something_new.something = None
    collection.clear()


def main():
    collection = list()
    for i in range(1, 1024 * 128):
        add_something(collection, i)

    check_memory(collection)


if __name__ == '__main__': main()
```

Если включить ручное вырезание ссылок (убрать комментарии), то все будет работать как часы, память освободиться мгновенно. Проверить можно использовав библиотеку https://pypi.org/project/memory-profiler/ и добавив аннотацию @profile перед функцией main.

Вопрос в практике. Есть ли у вас устоявшаяся практика, как избегать ручного очищения циклических ссылок? Буду признателен за любой совет. Спасибо!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1435415 и https://stackoverflow.com/q/865115

Comment: Да, там отличные ссылки, но это не совсем то. Проблема не в поиске и анализе утечек памяти. Проблема в том как правильно предотвращать. Циклические ссылки встречаются очень часто, по крайней мере, в том коде, который я видел.

Comment: вторая ссылка разве не показывает как предотвращать?

Comment: Да все правильно это один из вариантов. Но его применение требует тотальной переделки кода использование конструкции with больше подходит когда речь идет об освобождении внешних ресурсов. Такая практика принята не только в Python это отличная практика. Но переписать весь код через with. Это страшно. Может ошибаюсь, но должен же существовать "pythonic way".

Comment: Циклическая ссылка не является утечкой, однажды придёт сборщик мусора и почистит все циклы

Comment: Не совсем так, не обанывайте сами себя. В Python нет такого как например в Java - stop-world. Т.е. если память заканчивается будет выстрел SIGKILL и все, приложение просто мрет.

Comment: Тогда подскажите, как мне получить этот SIGKILL? Я сейчас написал простенький генератор циклических ссылок в while True и запустил на CPython — процесс скушал 6 гигабайт ОЗУ и больше не потребляет, swap выключен, SIGKILL отсутствует.

Comment: А с принудительным gc.collect() потребление памяти вообще не вылезает за 100МБ и никакого SIGKILL тем более возникнуть не может

Comment: Впрочем, при относительном бездействии программы сборщик мусора действительно не очень спешит выполнять свою работу, но если это действительно прям очень серьёзная проблема, ему можно «помочь» тем же вышеупомянутым gc.collect()

Comment: Ваш код работает из одной нитки? Это не совсем по теме вопроса, но что бы получить SIGKILL вам достаточно зажать нитку garbage коллектора. Например при нагрузке в 50 нитей это относительно легко получить. Кроме того, вызов gc.collect() не работает синхронно.

Может я не совсем точно сформулировал вопрос. Вопрос был по технике, которая позволяла бы быстро освобождать память без хаков при наличии циклических ссылок. Тот код который я привел, тривиален. В реальности ссылки идут через несколько классов объектов и отследить образование циклов не просто.

Comment: Да, с потоками действительно SIGKILL прилетел) Но городить целых 50 потоков в питоне это обычно не нормально, у него ж GIL. По технике лично я использую with и не парюсь